# Android GPS proximity alert not working

Tags: android, gps, alert, proximity

I'm trying to set up the most basic proximity alert, but nothing seems to happen. I'm fairly new to Android programming, so please let me know what I'm doing wrong or what am I missing. I got inspired from some source codes out here and [this one](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html). Here's my code:

```
package com.example.proximityalert;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.proximityalert";
    private IntentReceiver locationReminderReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

         LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         locationManager.addProximityAlert(55.586301,13.045417, 200, -1, pendingIntent);

         this.locationReminderReceiver = new IntentReceiver();

         final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
         this.registerReceiver(this.locationReminderReceiver, filter);

    }
}
```

and the Receiver

```
package com.example.proximityalert;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{  

//     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


          String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

          Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

          if (entering) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "LocationReminderReceiver entering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.i("LocationReminderReceiver", "entering");
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(context, "LocationReminderReceiver exiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.i("LocationReminderReceiver", "exiting");
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: try to move your intent and pendingintent to after you registerReciever

Comment: i've changed it to this, and still nothing..

`this.locationReminderReceiver = new IntentReceiver();
  
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
  this.registerReceiver(this.locationReminderReceiver, filter);
  
  Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locationManager.addProximityAlert(55.586301,13.045417, 200, -1, pendingIntent);`

Comment: mine works and the only diference is i have PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT and im running it in a service

Comment: would you please post the whole source code? maybe there's something I'm missing.. Also, did you declare the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: maybe it was that you have to declare your reciever as a BroadcastReciever and not an IntentReciever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the service that i use to get proximity alerts, your welcome to use it, it doesnt need the reciever in the manifest, just the service

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProximityService extends Service{
String proximitysd = "com.apps.ProximityService";
int n = 0;
private BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast;
private LocationManager locationManager;
MyLocationListener locationListenerp;
public ProximityService() {


}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mybroadcast = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);





    double lat;
    double lng;
    float radius = 50f;
    long expiration = -1;
     MyDBAdapter db = new MyDBAdapter(this);
        Cursor cursor;
        db.read();
        cursor = db.getAllEntries();
        boolean go = cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.isAfterLast() != true){
            lat = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LATITUDE_COLUMN)/1E6;
            lng = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LONGITUDE_COLUMN)/1E6;
            String what = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.ICON_COLUMN);
            String how = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.FISH_COLUMN);
            String proximitys = "com.apps.ProximityService" + n;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
            registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter );

            Intent intent = new Intent(proximitys);

            intent.putExtra("alert", what);
            intent.putExtra("type", how);
            PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, n, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);
            //sendBroadcast(new Intent(intent));

            n++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.d("reciever",e.toString());
    }


}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
    //registerReceiver(mybroadcast,filter);


}
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
     private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        String here = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");
        String happy = arg1.getExtras().getString("type");



         NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, arg1, 0);        

                Notification notification = createNotification();

                notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, 
                    "Entering Proximity!", "You are approaching a " + here + " marker.", pendingIntent);

                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


            }

            private Notification createNotification() {
                Notification notification = new Notification();

                notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
                notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
                notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
                notification.ledOffMS = 1500;


                return notification;
            }
        //make actions



}
 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

}
```

you would have to replace the database query and some of the code to fit your app, this is for multiple proximity alerts thats why there is the increment of n.

Comment: so I've deleted the db related stuff and extras, set the coordinates, defined the service in the manifest, and still nothing happens. It shows the toast that the service started, but no notification or anything on proximity. I also tried it on the phone, and set the coord with fakegps.. I have absolutely no idea why it's not working

`

Comment: i dont think it works in the emulator, it works, i know it does its on the marketplace right now

Comment: i found out why it wasn't working. when a proximity alert is defined, it is set (lat, lng), but in DDMS they are reversed :)))

Comment: glad you got it working, hope it comes to good use for you :)

Comment: i see absolutely no difference between using FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_ONE_SHOT. should there be any? however, they both create notifications every time i enter the radius and every time i exit the radius. i want it to create only one notification the first time i enter the radius and that all. (no notifications when i exit, and no notifications on future entering, but i don't want to stop the service)

Comment: i think use the boolean entering

Comment: @K-RAD - i am using the same code and an emulator but its still not working :( what am i missing ? could u help pliz