# Android - Alarm at location

Tags: android, location, alarm

Theoretic question. 
In my app I need to create alarm at location functionality.
So user can pick location, set alarm and any time while She/He
will get closer to location alarm will trigger.

I know that I have to create Service to listen the current 
location. It is obvious that I can't use GPS.

Any ideas how to figure it out if device is close to location?
I know that I still have Network location, which probably I will
use, but I afraid of that this will consume to much energy.

If there is any internal android system service which provide such
data? That I can just setup receiver.

Any ideas are welcome ;)

Comment: Why can't you use GPS ?

Comment: I don't want to waste battery life for periodically location check by using GPS.

Comment: "any internal android system service" - Google Play SDK. Available on devices with Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest building on Google Play Services in order to get the product working quickly. Of course if you need to target non-Google phones, then program this manually, but only if you have to.

Play offers Geofencing apis - here are the docs:

- [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

---

PROS:

- Google is constantly updating the Play sdk to optimise the features.
- quick to get it working
- battery efficiency

CONS:

- it will not work on non-Google API devices, i.e. Kindle Fire

Upshot of all this:

- if your app relies on Google Maps at all, then use the Play Geofencing.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use ProximityAlarm in Service.
Great example from this post:

[Android GPS proximity alert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428737/android-gps-proximity-alert-not-working)