# how to get the Distance in service while tracking the way in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have used from location and to location in my application....I got the exact distance using Google distance Api...in the same way,while we are moving on the road we have to calculate the distance in every location(Updatedly)?and when I reached my destination my tracking must be stopped?

please Help me Guys...

Comment: its not answer but idea,,,try to think and proceed.
First find the longitude and latitude of destination location and when you reach the destination location, find that longitude and latitude using android api and try compare and do the stuff you want..

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using Proximity alerts.

You need to store your destination in your device or in a db and then track your current location and once it reaches destination you can stop tracking or just provide a welcome message.

To use it as a service see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428737/android-gps-proximity-alert-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top):

Using a pending intent in your broadcast and then using a receiver you can track your location from the broadcast and compare with your stored destination. Tutorials available [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html)